# Superduper crash when copying partition and now my 1TB is showing 1GB it lost the MBR GUID how to recover it?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, ssd

Superduper crashed and now I cannot use my SSD (1TB)

The disk is a [Dell 960GB](https://www.serversupply.com/SSD/SATA-6GBPS/960GB/SAMSUNG/MZ7KH960HAJR0D3_317228.htm) you can see the image what it shows in Disk Utility

[image]

I already tried this:

```
diskutil info disk14

    Device Identifier:         disk14
   Device Node:               /dev/disk14
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk14
   Device / Media Name:       MZ7KH960HAJR0D3

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       None
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  SATA
   SMART Status:              Verified

   Disk Size:                 1.0 GB (1006260224 Bytes) (exactly 1965352 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Virtual:                   No
   Hardware AES Support:      No
```

and

```
sudo gpt recover disk14
gpt recover: disk14: no primary or secondary GPT headers, can't recover
```

and

```
diskutil verifyVolume disk14 
Error starting file system verification for disk14: Unrecognized file system (-69846)
```

and

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk14 count=1 skip=8 | xxd

1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes transferred in 0.000249 secs (2056225 bytes/sec)
00000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000100: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000140: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

and

```
sudo fdisk /dev/disk14

Disk: /dev/disk14   geometry: 974/32/63 [1965352 sectors]
Signature: 0x0
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

For what I've read I think this SSD is dead!

The disk is really a [Enterprise Samsung](https://www.senetic.pt/product/MZ7KH960HAJR-00005?gclid=Cj0KCQjwof6WBhD4ARIsAOi65ah8fyczhbVp9XQTNeyL_t64JfA6Fm4T-bxQmqJm1k9dxFpzW0aoCiYaApqeEALw_wcB)

Does anyone knows anymore tricks to help recreate the GUID mbr of this SSD?

Thanks